# Need some assistance with a regular expression please

Tags: regex

I want to replace a LabelFor command, using the Visual Studio replace tool

From:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.myRecords.First().Column1)
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.myRecords.First().M.M.Column2)
```

To

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.myRecords.First().Column1, null, Model.Status)
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.myRecords.First().M.M.Column2, null, Model.Status)
```

I have used "Column1" and "Column2" as examples of 2 columns which should remain unchanged after the replacement ie addition of :

```
, null, Model.Status)
```

to end of statement.

I suspect I need a regular expression to identify the last ")" and then to replace with

```
    , null, Model.Status)
```

Thoughts appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `)` is the last char of the line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to match the last brace, with `\)$` (globally and multiline)

Then replace with your string `, null, Model.Status)`

[Regexr solution](http://regexr.com/3cu44)